# Use of if else inside a dict to set a value to key using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am looking for a way to use if else condition in a dictionary to set a value to a key. Is there a way?

The example below might help you understand what I want to do. This is not a functional Python code. Just an example to give you an idea.

```
age = 22
di = {
    'name': 'xyz',
    if age>=18:
        'access_grant': 'yes',
    else:
        'access_grant': 'no',
     }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this would be a perfect opportunity to use a [ternary expression](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) (python also calls this the "ternary operator"):

```
...
di = {
    'name': 'xyz',
    'access_grant': 'yes' if age >= 18 else 'no',
 } 
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can separate the logic from the dictionary with a function:

```
def access_grant(age):
    return 'yes' if age >= 18 else 'no'

age = 22
di = {
    'name': 'xyz',
    'access_grant': access_grant(age),
}
```

Having the logic outside of the dictionary makes it easier to test and reuse.

Answer (score 3):

Set as many items as you can in the initial definition, then add the others afterwards:

```
age = 22
di = {
    'name': 'xyz',
    ... other known keys here
}
if age>=18:
    di['access_grant'] = 'yes'
else:
    di['access_grant'] = 'no'
```